# Delete a subsite when all permissions have been removed

Tags: 2007, permissions

I created a subsite on sharepoint 2007, and when editing user permissions I have accidentally deleted all permissions including Team site owners. So now no one has permissions to add/modify or delete this subsite.

Is there a way of deleting a subsite using the sharepoint 3.0 central administration tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete a subsite in central admin, no.  The site collection owners should still have access to everything even if permissions are removed.  Whoever is listed as either of the 2 owners of the site collection in Central Admin's Site Collection Administrators link has the ability to delete the subsite with no permissions.

You can temporarily set yourself as one of the listed users and delete the subsite.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure some user account to act as System Account in Central Administration by configuring web application policy. See the details here: http://grounding.co.za/blogs/neil/archive/2008/06/23/controlling-security-in-sharepoint-using-quot-web-application-policies-quot.aspx Then you will be able to login to SharePoint as System Account and to do everything you want without any restrictions. After complition your task you should delete your policy changes back.